# map is not a function in Angular 5

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, angular5

I am trying to get values between two dates. In server side its working fine but in front end it's show me error as **birthdays.map is not a function**

**birthday.service.ts**

```
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import * as moment from 'moment';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
    import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

   getbirthdays(start?: moment.Moment, end?: moment.Moment): 
   Observable<birthday[]> {
        let params = new HttpParams();

        if (start) {
          params = params.append('start', start.toISOString());
        }

        if (end) {
          params = params.append('end', end.toISOString());
        }

        return this.http.get('/api/birthday', {params: params}).pipe(
          map(res => res as Object[] || []),
          map(birthdays => birthdays.map(k => new birthday(
            k['_id'],
            new Date(k['datetime']),
            k['gift']))
          )
        );
      }
```

**error in browser console**

> core.js:1350 ERROR TypeError: birthdays.map is not a function
>       at MapSubscriber.project (birthday.service.ts:28)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:35)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:41)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:41)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at FilterSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next
>   (filter.js:38)
>       at FilterSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext

Answer (score 3):

The Typescript's type checking works for compile-time only and, because it's compiled to JavaScript at the end anyway, all the typings are for developer information only as Typescript has no runtime type check/cast feature

That's why `map(res => res as Object[] || [])` won't cast the response to `Array` it'll only tell the IDE what type the response data is (for your information only), it won't modify the data itself (you can define res as `Object[]`, but if the backend sends you the `Object`, you'll get the same exact object anyway.

If you want to use `Array.prototype.map` you need to manually parse the response to `Array`.

You should remove the first `map()` as it does nothing and set the `debugger;` in the second to see what data you're getting.